# Refreshing the page does not update the recent javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I wrote a javascript code inside an codeigniter page but when i refresh the page the previous code is still there. I tried opening it in incognito and it was updated and working. Why is that?

Comment: try after clear cache or ctrl+f5

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Anyways i tried refreshing the server too but i didn't update the code. What is the difference of ctrl+f5 and clicking the address bar and hitting enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser is caching css and js file.
So sometimes when you refresh it load files from previously stored cache.

Reload all fresh file use - ctrl+f5 or ctrl+shift+f5

Read more ---> [Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)